# Find words with underscores in excel worksheet by using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

Is it possible to search/ parse through two columns in excel (let's say columns C & D) and find only the fields with underscores by using python?
Maybe a code like this? Not too sure..:

```
Import xl.range 
Columns = workbook.get("C:D"))
Extract = re.findall(r'\(._?)\', str(Columns)
```

Please let me know if my code can be further improved on! :)

Comment: short answer is yes!! but if you need help with the code Please try to implement something and share here to get help with the issue you are facing. Forum is to help in leaning and fixing issues.

Comment: Thanks @toheedniaz :) see my edited post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who need an answer, I solved it via using this code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
dict_folder = "C:/...../abc"
for file in os.listdir(dict_folder):
  if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
  wb1 = load_workbook(join(dict_folder, file), data_only = True)
  ws = wb1.active

for rowofcellobj in ws["C" : "D"]:
 for cellobj in rowofcellobj:
    data = re.findall(r"\w+_.*?\w+", str(cellobj.value))
    if data != []:
       fields = data[0]
       fieldset.add(fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is indeed possible. The main lib you'll get to for that is `pandas`. With it installed (instructions [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/)) after, of course, installing python, you could do something along the lines of

```py
import pandas as pd

# Reading the Excel worksheet into a pandas.DataFrame type object
sheet_path = 'C:\\Path\\to\\excel\\sheet.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(sheet_path)

# Using multiple conditions to find column substring within
underscored = df[(df['C'].str.contains('_')) | (df['D'].str.contains('_'))]
```

And that'd do it for columns `C` and `D` within your worksheet.

`pandas` has got a very diverse documentation, but to the extent you're looking for, the [`read_excel` function documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) (has examples) will suffice, along with some more content on python itself, if needed.

Comment: hey there, thanks so much :) But I dont want to use pandas here!

Comment: No problem :) for clearance though, next time please specify that in your question. That way others here will be able to help better.